# Observe UIView frame while animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have multiple `UIView`s that are dependant on each other, a `UIView` can change its frame.

Other `UIView`s respond accordingly to the currently changing `UIView`.

however, a `UIView` changes its frame with animations, I tried to observe a `UIView`'s `frame` property but it gives me the last result after it starts animating.

Here's my current setup:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: [NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old, .new, .prior, .initial], context: nil)

}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if let obj = object as? UIView {
        print(obj.layer.frame.minY)
    }
}
```

Example of the result when I observed the `obj.layer.frame.minY`:

622.0
252.0

**My problem is:**

I want to observe the current `obj.layer.frame.minY` while animating.

**Update:**

I tried to use the presentation() method, but I still get the same result. Here's how I do it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
//        print("value of \(keyPath) changed: \(change![NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey])")

    if let obj = object as? UIView {
        guard let presentation = obj.layer.presentation() else { return }
        let a = presentation
        print(a)

    }

}
```

Comment: The view's own frame is not animated, only the presentation layer's.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I tried it. same result. I've updated my question of how I use it.

Comment: You can't use KVO for this. Look at the linked answers.